# Optimise Performance - OpenCV and Threads with Python

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, python-multithreading

I am having a problem related to performance using **OpenCV3.2** with **Python**. I have just integrated another subsystem to my main program and it slowed down a lot.

This is my initial code **without** integrating the new subsystem, I am using `cv2.getTickCount` to measure time, as suggested by [OpenCv3.2 Official Website](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/d71/tutorial_py_optimization.html).

```
# Infinite loop
while True:
    # getting tick count
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    # storing frame
    _, img = cap.read()

    # define red colours in the screen
    findRedColours(img, board)
    # getting tick count after the functions
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    # calculating time
    t = (e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency()
    # print time
    print(t)

    # check if img is none
    if img is not None:
        # omitted code

        k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
        # start the game, hide info
        if (k == ord('s') or k == ord('S')) and start is False:
            # create new thread to play game
            t = Thread(target=playGame)
            t.start()
```

Basically, I am calling a function in the infinite loop to find red colours and by pressing start I create the Thread and the game starts.

This is the time needed **before** I press 'S' to create the Thread:

```
0.019336862
0.016924178
0.022487864
```

This is the time needed **after** I press 'S' to create the Thread:

```
0.091731532
0.125760734
0.098221829
```

Here everything works fine, there is a light change in the time, but nothing too important. I start to have problems when I add my new subsystem. Here the following code **with the integration of the new system**, it is the same of the previous one, it is just a function call that changes:

```
# Infinite loop
    while True:
        # getting tick count
        e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
        # storing frame
        _, img = cap.read()
        # extract grid
        gridExtractor.extractGrid(img)
        # define red colours in the screen
        findRedColours(img, board)
        # getting tick count after the functions
        e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
        # calculating time
        t = (e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency()
        # print time
        print(t)

        # check if img is none
        if img is not None:
            # omitted code

            k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
            # start the game, hide info
            if (k == ord('s') or k == ord('S')) and start is False:
                # create new thread to play game
                t = Thread(target=playGame)
                t.start()
```

and this is the time **before** I create the Thread:

```
0.045629524
0.023788123
0.10517206
```

It is slightly higher than the one without the integration, but still ok. Here is the time **after** I create Thread:

```
1.061517957
0.568310864
0.691701059
```

There is an enormous difference between this one and the previous one, it reaches even a whole second. It is noticeable even from the camera output, really slow.

My questions are, am I creating my Thread in the wrong way? There is a better and more efficient way to use rather the Threads? Or is there actually a way to optimise performance in this case without having to modify these functions `findRedColours(img, board)`, `t = Thread(target=playGame)`, `gridExtractor.extractGrid(img)`?

I am new using OpenCV and Python and still having troubles around. Hope someone can address me to the right way. Thanks.

Comment: Am I getting it right, that you start every 20ms a thread, if 's' was pressed?

Comment: No, I create the Thread just once after I press the key 'S'.

Comment: I find your description hard to decipher, but one thing pops out: if you try & use threads for enhancing performance, this will *fail* in Python. It's using a GIL (global interpreter lock) that effectively allows only one thread to be running. One can use threads, and  they are useful for waiting for blocking IO - but if you want to utilize e.g. several cores, use multiple processe & inter process communication (see multiprocessing-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user 'deets' who help commenting above it has been possible to **optimise performance**.

In this case is enough to substitute Thread with Process from [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) module in Python.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
#omitted code

while True:
    # getting tick count
    e1 = cv2.getTickCount()
    # storing frame
    _, img = cap.read()
    # extract grid - first subsystem
    gridExtractor.extractGrid(img)
    # define red colours in the screen - second subsystem
    findRedColours(img, board)
    # getting tick count after the functions
    e2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    # calculating time
    t = (e2 - e1) / cv2.getTickFrequency()
    # print time
    print(t)

    # check if img is none
    if img is not None:
        # omitted code

        k = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
        # start the game, hide info
        if (k == ord('s') or k == ord('S')) and start is False:
            # create new thread to play game
            p = Process(target=playGame)
            p.start()
```

And the relative time needed is:

```
0.022570883
0.11354852
0.119643379
```

Compared to Thread the use of Process is way more efficient in terms of performance.